# Can't cacth nameError in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror, simpy

Here is my code:

```
from SimPy.Simulation import *

class Message(Process):
    def arrive(self, destination):
        yield hold, self, 2
        try:
            print "%s %s going to %s" % (now(), self.name, destination.name)
            self.interrupt(destination)
        except NameError, x:
            print "%s is out of reach" % x
```

What I want to do is to print out that destination is unreachable when its name doesn't exist, but I'm still getting usual python error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    message.arrive(node2)
NameError: name 'node2' is not defined
```

Comment: Where are you calling `message.arrive(node2)`?

Comment: i just wrote it in shell

Comment: Then you didn't define `node2`.

Comment: Yes i didnt. I want it to catch an exception if some node is trying to reach a node that desn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your name error does not occur in the method. It occurs *before* the method is called.

Python tries to resolve `node2` before it can pass the value of `node2` to the `message.arrive()` method. The method code is never executed.

You'd get the same error if you just typed `node2` in your shell, you did not define it so Python doesn't know how to use it's value then either.

Comment: Hmm, guess you are wright. Any idea how to throw an exception in that case?

Comment: @tobi: it *already* is throwing an exception in that case, a `NameError`. If you meant how to catch it: Write the `try:` `except` in the shell instead.